# Forefront TMG for SharePoint 2010 application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, forefront

I have few doubts on TMG. I have listed all. Pl reply for all points.

1. TMG servers are not used in SharePoint 2010 intranet application rather used only in Internet applications.
2. If any SharePoint 2010 intranet application is having a module where channel partners are accessing it & FBA implemented with SQL, is it better or necessary to deploy through TMG server? I mean is  TMG required just because partners will access...?
3. Since Microsoft is going to discontinue TMG with other forefront products should we continue with TMG ?
4. Is there any other replacement for TMG?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

ForeFront TMG is mainly used indeed for intranet/extranet scenarios. Unless you really have valid reasons to secure or redirect traffic in Intranet, you are adding more complexity otherwise. But you could envision having it running still relying on simple DNS for the redirection of internal calls.

Giving partners access falls under extranet (usually HTTPS), so particularly publishing SharePoint URLs it is recomanded with TMG, whether you decide to use it as Reverse-Proxy or off-load SSL terminations.

The better alternative for TMG is currently UAG.

Comment: hi marius, thanks for your reply. pl explain UAG .

Comment: What are compelling reason for an intranet application to go  for TMG implementation? Exactly when we should decide for TMG for an intranet application?

Comment: could be perimeter networks with different vlans, security concerns, reduced ports/applications availability due mainly to policies in places.